# mpirun gets higher rank than requested with --ntasks from sbatch script

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, slurm

I am launching a MPI program through a SBATCH script like this (corresponding to an example script provided by the system administrators):

```
#! /bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH -o stdout.log
#SBATCH -e stderr.log
#SBATCH --ntasks=160
#SBATCH --time=0-00:10:00
#SBATCH --qos=normal

cd $WORK/

mpirun ./mpiprogram
```

However, it seems that sometimes more MPI processes are launched than NTASKS. Resulting in sometimes 200 processes when 160 was requested, sometimes different numbers. Note that the nodes have 16 or 20 cores. Some of the worker processes (all pretty much identical in my case) run much slower than the others, perhaps because of swapping. The swapping may be caused by too many processes on one node, causing them to use too much memory.

Should I specify the number of threads to mpirun using `$SLURM_NTASKS`? Or what is going on here?

Comment: Which MPI library and version are you using ?

Comment: When running the job what are the values of the env vars: `SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE`, `SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE`,`SLURM_NNODES`, `SLURM_NTASKS`, `SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE` and `SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Intel MPI, version 5.1.3

Comment: @TimothyBrown: Here's a case where I got 150 when 160 was requested: http://ix.io/zMI

Comment: `size` in the last output line from my program is retrieved from `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()` using `mpi4py`.

Comment: @gauteh I'm not a python programmer... Those `TASK_PER_NODES` total 160. Can you get more specific info from MPI? Such as printing the `Get_rank()`, `Get_size()` and `MPI.Get_processor_name()`. Then check that against the `TASK_PER_NODES` layout? Also since your using Intel MPI, can you set the env var `I_MPI_DEBUG=5` [doc](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/535536). Have you tried `srun` or `mpiexec` or `mpiexec.hydra`?

Comment: I remember some MPI process managers not working properly with `sbatch`. I strongly suggest to use `srun` as suggested by @TimothyBrown and see if the problem is solved. Using Intel MPI, check the value of the variable `I_MPI_HYDRA_BOOTSTRAP`, which selects the resource manager engine to be used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the other launchers. It does admittedly seem to be `mpirun` that is at fault. `mpirun` was recommended by the system administrators for this computer though.

Comment: Also if you use `srun` you will more than likely have to set the env var `I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY` to the slurm PMI library (normally is `$SLURM_ROOT/lib/libpmi.so`).

Comment: `mpiexec.hydra -bootstrap slurm` results in 146 processes to be launched (for 160).

Comment: Ok, so what finally seems to work: First load newer `impi` which supports `python 3`, then use `I_MPI_HYDRA_BOOTSTRAP=slurm` (don't know if this has any effect) and `I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY=/.../libpmi.so`.

Comment: Does any of you want to add an answer about `I_PMI_LIBRARY` and launching with `srun`?